# Using python 2.7 and regex to find substring using beginning and end of substring (codons)

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

(python 2.7) I have a RNA sequence and I am trying to find all the non-overlaping substrings that start with 'AUG' and end in either 'UAG' or 'UGA' or 'UAA'
this is what I'm working with:

```
import re
sequence = GAUGCAAAAUAAAUGAUGUAAUAA
search = r"^(AUG(.)*(?:UAG|UAA|UGA))" 
regions = re.findall(search, sequence)
print regions
```

The output should be "AUGCAAAA" and "AUGAUG". However I am getting the entire region 'AUGCAAAAUAAAUGAUGUAAUAA'

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to use

```
AUG.*?(?=UAG|UAA|UGA)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cz9A0z/1)

**Details**:

- `AUG` - match `AUG`
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible up to the first...
- `(?=UAG|UAA|UGA)` - `UAG` or `UAA` or `UGA` (that are not part of the return value since the pattern is inside a positive lookahead that is a zero-width assertion).

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly.  I made a typo when I put a ':' instead of a '='.  But i wasn't aware of the '.*?' to pick the shortest possible sequence.

Comment: Actually, `.*?` does not pick the shortest possible sequence, it only matches up to the leftmost occurrence of the subsequent subpattern. [`a.*?c`](https://regex101.com/r/xEn5qs/3) will match `abac` in `tabacic`, not `ac`.